# Responsive design + jQuery fine except Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I'm using some pretty basic jQuery to force things into position when they are moved around:

```
function ipad() {
var width = jQuery(window).width();
if (width < 1200 && width >= 768){ //if tablet 
jQuery('.mobbut').css('width', '33.333%');
jQuery('#re2').css('max-width', '');
} else {
jQuery('.mobbut').css('width', '100%'); 
jQuery('#re2').css('max-width', '400px');
}
if (width < 768){  //if mobile phone
jQuery('._btnselect').hide();   
} else {
jQuery('._btnselect').show();   
}
}

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
ipad();//run when page first loads
});
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
ipad();//run on every window resize
});
jQuery(window).load(function() {
ipad();//run when page is fully loaded
});
```

So far my website is perfect on Chrome, Safari, iPad, iPhone, but for some reason it looks a mess when you resize your Firefox window to smaller than 1200px wide. Try for yourself [here's the webpage](http://7connections.com). Is it something to do with the jQuery or more the layout of the page? I inherited this homepage from another designer and it was previously built on tables so this may be giving FF problems.

Comment: Why you don't use media queries? http://css-tricks.com/css-media-queries/

Comment: ^ This is exactly what media queries are made for.

Comment: I tried using media queries and they didn't work, I had to turn to jQuery to get the results.

Comment: It seems the problem was Firefox's width being determined by the width of the largest image on screen, instead of resizing the image to fit the window...

Answer (score 1):

> I tried using media queries and they didn't work, I had to turn to jQuery to get the results.

If they didn't work, it's probably because the syntax was incorrect. Try it like this, which is pretty much exactly what your jQuery is doing, but much simpler:

```
#re2 {
  max-width: 400px;
}
.mobbut {
  width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  ._btnselect {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1199px) {
  #re2 {
    max-width: none;
  }
  .mobbut {
    width: 33.333%;
  }
}
```

--EDIT--

Since it looks like you're trying to target the iPad. Try these media queries, from [this post](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/media-queries-for-standard-devices/):

```
/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
/* Styles */
}

/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
/* Styles */
}
```

These will likely work even more reliably than your jQuery adjustments since they are based on the `device-width` rather than the page `width`.

Answer (score 0):

I ran your site with [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) (I do recommend using it) enabled and the error is in the following function

```
** function futsal(){
   var wid = jQuery(window).width();
   if (wid <= 1024 && width >= 768){ //if tablet **
```

just there you declare the var wid and then test against width

I agree with all of the comments above though, use media queries.  It's far easier.

Comment: Any idea why this is producing an error and how to fix it?

Comment: @user3589055 As dops mentioned, what is "width" to this function? You probably meant "wid".

Comment: @MiniRagnarok wid is the variable, but I see a mistake now, I have written width instead of wid. Now that this has been fixed the site still looks awful in a screen size smaller than 1200 except for the footer now works fine.

Comment: @user3589055 Honestly, I don't think you're going to have much luck trying to make a site made in tables responsive. Sometimes you have to bite the bullet and tell your superiors/clients that what they are asking for is unreasonable. Making a site responsive has few shortcuts.

Comment: It seems the problem was Firefox's width being determined by the width of the largest image on screen, instead of resizing the image to fit the window...